# Meaning of "in a look of a frame of reference"

Tags: phrases, differences, idioms

Does "in a look of a frame of reference" mean "regarding to sth."? Sorry, unfortunately I couldn't find a simple example.

Comment: Do you have a complicated example, then? Even Google doesn't have a single hit for this weird turn of phrase. That's saying something. We'll take any and all additional information you can provide.

Comment: To me, your expression doesn't make sense and I don't know what you are trying to say. You might want to try the **English Language Learners** site at http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Heard it once and tried to check the meaning, but couldn't find any useful information. Example via Google: "A closer look at the frame-of-reference effect in personality scale scores and validity."

Comment: That example doesn't even match the question. It's a completely different structure. The only words it has in common with your question are *look* and *frame of reference*, which can be looked up in a dictionary of your choice. It is not clear at all what you are asking. If you can edit your question to clarify, it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

As TrevorD notes in a comment, “in a look of a frame of reference” makes little sense.  The form shown in a comment of your own, however, is more easily understood:

> A closer look at the frame-of-reference effect in personality scale scores and validity

In this title (which is not a sentence),  “A closer look”  refers to a more-detailed study or perusal of something, namely “the frame-of-reference effect”, which (in the context of [personality scales](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/5490020_A_closer_look_at_the_frame-of-reference_effect_in_personality_scale_scores_and_validity/file/d912f50dd667c826b2.pdf)) means having a basis or standard of comparison.

Generally, “frame of reference” does not give a meaning related to “regarding to”, but phrases like “in the context of” and “in the framework of” might.